# Find Directory of Target File on Remote Server

Tags: windows, powershell, domain, remote

I am trying to find a file directory on a list of remote servers.  I want to:

1. Use Powershell; get targets from comma delimited text file, i.e. server1,file1
   Note:  file is different for each server.
2. Search the C: and E: partitions for a file, even if more than one instance of it
3. Get the file directory
4. Write the result to a .csv
5. View the output on the Powershell main window

Here is the script I have been working with.  I cannot get it to work properly.  I need some help:

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path 
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
$FileName = "$dir\Servers.txt"
$Data = gc $FileName

foreach ($Row in $Data)
    {
    $Position = $Row.IndexOf(",")
    $Server = $Row.Substring(0, $Position)
    $File = $Row.Substring($Position + 1)

    $CPart = @{
       Name = "CPart"
       Path = "\\$Server\C$"
       #Path = "FileSystem::\\$Server\C$"
    }

    $EPart = @{
       Name = "EPart"
       Path = "\\$Server\E$"
       #Path = "FileSystem::\\$Server\E$"
    }

    @($CPart, $EPart) | ForEach-Object {
        if ($Server -like "*.mydomain.com") {$session = New-PSSession -Computer $Server -Credential MYDOMAIN\userid -ErrorAction Stop}
        else {$Session = New-PSSession -Computer $Server -ErrorAction Stop}
        Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$Result = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $_.Path | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '$File'};return $Result}
        $Result
        #$item = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $_.Path | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '$File' -and }
        #Write-Host $item
    }
}
    
<#foreach ($Server in $Servers) 
    {
    "\\$Server\C$" | Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter $FileList | Select Directory, Name | Write-Host $_.Directory + "\" + $_.Name
    "\\$Server\E$" | Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter $FileList | Select Directory, Name | Write-Host $_.Directory + "\" + $_.Name
}

$columnToGet = 0
$columns = gc $fileName | 
   %{ $_.Split(",")[$columnToGet] }
$columns
#>
```

Comment: take a look at the `CIM_DataFile` class. you can use CIM or WMI to call it with the target system, drive, and file ... and it will return info on what it finds.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I read up on both (https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/cim_datafile) and it seems they are prohibitive on remote, recursive searches for files because WMI first collects the entire contents of a partition before it performs any filtering (finding).  I am really looking for someone to help me use get-childitem recursively on a remote server partition hopefully in a way that will not take all day long.

Comment: the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet will also need to read thru the entire volume to find any files _if you don't know the dir tree to limit the search to_. ///// the robocopy command with the "list only" option would be fairly fast ... and - like the G-CI cmdlet - it can be run with `Invoke-Command` to run things in parallel on each target system. then it  would send the final result back to the calling system.